# Show that $3\int_{[0,1)} |f|d\lambda+4\int_{[1,2]} |f|d\lambda\leq 5\bigg( \int_{[0,2]} |f|^2d\lambda \bigg)^{1/2}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In some homework I have to show that for $f \in \mathcal{L}^2([0,2],\lambda)$ then:
$$3\int_{[0,1)} |f|d\lambda+4\int_{[1,2]} |f|d\lambda\leq 5\bigg( \int_{[0,2]} |f|^2d\lambda \bigg)^{1/2}$$

But I have run out of good ideas. I tried applying Pythagoras and Minkowski but with no luck

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: the numbers $(3,4,5)$ are a [Pythagorean triplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), so we have a "hint" now

Comment: Why did you delete the other question ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Because the question was not correctly formulated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, by Hoelder inequality
$$
3 \int_{[0,1)} |f| + 4 \int_1^2 |f| \le 3 (\int_{[0,1)} |f|^2 ) ^{1/2} + 4 (\int_{[1,2]} |f| ^2)^{1/2}.
$$
Then by Cauchy-Schwarz on $\mathbb R^2$
$$ 
3 (\int_{[0,1)} |f|^2 ) ^{1/2} + 4 (\int_{[1,2]} |f| ^2)^{1/2}
= \pmatrix{3 \\ 4}^T\cdot \pmatrix{ ( \int \dots)^{1/2} \\ (\int \dots)^{1/2}}\\
\le \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} \sqrt{ \int_{[0,1)} |f|^2  + \int_{[1,2]} |f| ^2}
= 5 \sqrt{\int_{[0,2)} |f|^2}
$$

Comment: I am not sure how you use Hölder. Is this because you are extending like this? $ \int_{[0,1)} 3\cdot |f| +  \int_{[1,2]} 4\cdot |f| \le (\int_{[0,1)} 3^2 ) ^{1/2} \cdot (\int_{[0,1)} |f|^2 ) ^{1/2} + (\int_{[1,2]} 4^2)^{1/2}\cdot (\int_{[1,2]} |f| ^2)^{1/2}=3 (\int_{[0,1)} |f|^2 ) ^{1/2} + 4 (\int_{[1,2]} |f| ^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: exactly, $\int |f| \le (\int 1^2)^{1/2} (\int |f|^2)^{1/2}$.